# supporting of TCL in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, tcl

does sqlite in iphone supports TCL commands?
Do we need to give explicitly or its done automatically?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a database.
TCL is an interpreter language (scripting).
You can call SQLite from within tcl with the proper interface/package/lib: http://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html
You need to check if you're able to run tcl code from the app/location you're working on.

Could also be possible with a execute command to run tclsh with the proper params. You just need to validate this, then this is your answer.